# Listing all the storage drives in ESXi

Tags: parsing, vmware, esxi

I am trying to automate the collection of disk information such as Manufcaturer, model,type (ex HDD ,SSD , nvme) and size of each of all the storage hardware on the server to keep track of server hardware configuration over time for our test rig. I have used a bunch of commands to get information about all the SSDs, HDDs and NVME  installed on my server that uses the ESXi hypervisor. I am trying to parse the output of these commands

```
esxcli storage core device list
esxcli storage core adapter list
lspci |grep -i storage
esxcfg-scsidevs  -a
```

Each of these partially provide the information I need, however I am not able to piece them together since I am not able to identify a common key to use for each of the drives that appears in the outputs of all these commands. Is there an esxi command that I can use where all the information I need is located at one place.

Comment: Are you wanting to collect this information locally on the ESXi host or remotely? I think it would be easier to parse that information easier remotely using PowerCLI or an SDK, but don't know if that fits your scenario.

Comment: Locally on the esxi host.although how could I do this via powercli ?